# Rename [custom-notificaiton] due to typo

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest to change the tag [custom-notificaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-notificaiton) to [custom-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-notification) (...a**it**on to ...a**ti**on).

Currently [38 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-notificaiton) are tagged [custom-notificaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-notificaiton). It has no usage guidance or tag wiki.

That's the only [notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notification)-tag with this misspelling and my google search didn't reveal anything programming-related actually named "custom-notificaiton". Also when looking at the questions, they correctly write "notification" or "custom notification", so the mistake is only in the tag.

A few exemplary titles:

- [Remoteview displays system notification when App is not in the foreground or not running instead of Custom Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56946146/11682469)
- [How to set custom notification icons from URL image Nougat and above OS Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49068449/11682469)
- [How to send custom notification in iOS using Firebase Notifications.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47070546/11682469)
- [Android Big Custom Notification with Action buttons in API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33758402/11682469) (the oldest question I found)
  to show that it was probably not intentional.

Comment: What is the purpose of this tag? Why do we need it at all?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Let's burn it instead

Comment: I was reading it, it seems to be used mostly for android-notifications, but there are non android nor android-notifications questions, so merging isn't possible  either. Manual clean up seems to be the best option here.